# Update database using EF 6 database first fetch all the relational tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework, linq

i use to update database table by following linq.

```
var pr = dbEntities.Ac_ProductReceive.FirstOrDefault<Ac_ProductReceive>(x => x.ID == 6);

            if (pr != null)
            {
                pr.ServiceStatus = pr.IsIndoorReceive ? "C" : "DEL";
                pr.IsAssigned = false;
                pr.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                pr.UpdatedBy = 155;
            }
            dbEntities.SaveChanges();
```

But the `FirstOrDefault` fetching all the relational table related by foreign key relation ship more than 6 tables.This causes High CPU and performance issues in my application.
 I tried `Find()` method  but still the same!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

So my question is how to update database without fetching all tables for single rows.

N.B. I can use `dbEntities.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()` but i am against using raw sql other EF linq.

Comment: "*Five exclamation marks, the sure sign of an insane mind.*" (Terry Pratchett, *Reaper Man*). So what to make of twenty four!?

Comment: My product IIS causes 70-80 % CPU usages for last 5 months .After analysis we found this may be the potential cause for HIGH cpu as we use more update for our project  ....Sure i am worried :(

Comment: Are your entity relations configured for eager loading? (See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj574232).)

Comment: I can imagine that you do not have lazy loading enabled in your EF configuration (or not configured properly), that's why EF is loading all foreign keys as related objects of your data.

Comment: Probably you are doing most of the things wrong, for example : 1. lazy load is enabled by default ( you haven't disabled it)  2. You had tried to implement a repository pattern which you have very less knowledge and there is a heavy lifting going on that you don't know of. 3. If you are using EF then by default you should get the exact type why do you need to have the <type> there?

Comment: Thanks @ Richard. It may be the cause.Some times a little help saves a lot of brainstroming